# ¿Cómo puedo crear una serie de objetos dentro de un ciclo for en python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, objeto, class, exec

Quiero crear una serie de objetos de la forma.

```
Image_N = Image(N,k)
```

Donde N es mi variable del ciclo for y Image(N,k) es mi clase para definir a cada objeto; notece que los atributos de mi clase están dados ambos por ciclos for de la siguiente forma

```
for k in list_1:
  for N in list_2:
    ##Aqui es donde quiero meter la función que me permita crear los objetos. 
    ## Image_N = Image(N,k)
```

Son alrededor de 100 objetos, por lo que hacerlos de uno por uno no es conveniente.
Muchas gracias.

Intente lo siguiente:

```
for i in cars_train_annos:
  Image_car = i[5][0].replace('.jpg','')
  Class_car = i[4][0][0]
  k=0
  for j in cars_meta:
    k=k+1
    if k == Class_car:
      exec('Image_{} = Image(Class_car,k,j)'.format(Image_car))
```

Pero me manda el siguiente error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-d18a75421459> in <module>()
      8     if k == Class_car:
      9       #print('Image: ' + str(Image_car) + '--' + 'Class: ' + str(Class_car))
---> 10       exec('Image_{} = Image(Class_car,k,j)'.format(Image_car))

<string> in <module>()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Crear 100 variables con el mismo nombre que se diferencian tan solo por un sufijo, tales como las `Image_1`, `Image_2`, `Image_3` etc que pretendes, no es buena idea (y las dificultades que has encontrado para lograrlo ya son un aviso de que por ahí no es el camino). Aún si las consiguieras crear ¿cómo las usarías por ejemplo dentro de otro bucle? Te obligaría de nuevo a andar haciendo "filigranas" del estilo del `exec()` para poder acceder a sus contenidos.

La forma correcta de hacer esto es, naturalmente, una lista o un diccionario.

### Usando una lista

```
image = []
for k in list_1:
  for N in list_2:
    image.append(Image(N, k))
```

Al terminar tendrás en la lista `image` todas las imágenes creadas. Podrás acceder a la primera de ellas usando `image[0]`, a la segunda usando `image[1]`, etc...

Si quisieras iterar por ellas en orden puedes usar un bucle:

```
for im in image:
   # .. hacer algo con im
```

El problema de este enfoque es que tal vez los índices de la lista, que son siempre 0, 1, 2, etc... no coincidan con los valores de `N` con los que fuiste creando las imágenes. Para este segundo caso puede ser mejor un diccionario.

### Usando un diccionario

```
image = {}
for k in list_1:
  for N in list_2:
     image[N] = Image(N, k)
```

De este modo puedes acceder a una imagen cualquiera, digamos la que tenía N=5 escribiendo simplemente `image[5]`.

El inconveniente de los diccionarios, si usas una versión de Python inferior a la 3.7, es que cuando intentes iterar por ellos puedes obtenerlos en orden diferente a como los elementos fueron insertados:

```
for N, im in image.items():
   print("Imagen {}".format(N))
   # ... hacer algo con im
```

Puedes encontrarte que las N no te salen en el orden esperado. Aunque a partir de python3.7 los diccionarios garantizan el orden de inserción (el orden en que los elementos fueron añadidos al diccionario).

Answer (score 0):

parece que estás comparando un integer con una clase. Esta última debería de tener una propiedad a la que pudieses acceder:

```
for i in cars_train_annos:
  Image_car = i[5][0].replace('.jpg','')
  Class_car = i[4][0][0]
  k=0
  for j in cars_meta:
    k=k+1
    if k == Class_car.k:
      exec('Image_{} = Image(Class_car,k,j)'.format(Image_car))
```